# Java setLocation() mishap

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jdialog, joptionpane

I'm in the beginning stages of creating a program to operate an Employee/Customer system, right now I have just created the Login GUI, but I am having a little bit of a problem with the

```
setLocation();
```

method. I set it to 250, 250, but it makes the height of my GUI go absolutely nuts. My code is below if anyone would be able to fix this.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    private static final int HEIGHT = 1003;
    private static final int WIDTH = 400;

    JTextField _uid = new JTextField(10);
    JPasswordField _pwd = new JPasswordField(10);
    JButton _login = new JButton("Login");
    JButton _reset = new JButton("Reset");

    public Main() {
       super("Login - Durptech");
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        add(new JLabel("User ID:"));
            add(_uid);
        add(new JLabel("Password:"));
            add(_pwd);

            add(_login);
            add(_reset);
                _reset.addActionListener(new ResetButtonHandler());


       setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
       setVisible(true);
       setResizable(false);
       setLocation(250, 250);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private class ResetButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            _uid.setText("");
            _pwd.setText("");
            _uid.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Comment: The height of your application **is** absolutely nuts -- 1003!

Comment: LOOOOOOOOL. Can't believe I missed that. OH GOD LOL.

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/), but save `setVisible()` for last.

Comment: Yeah, this is just a rough start, once I have it all setup (database, different panels for employee/customer) I'm going to clean it all up and everything will be modular.

Comment: Better not keep the good suggestions for the end, do make the changes as you come to know of them, by putting comments, that's how you learn things, else who knows, you again might forget many things as the project finishes and again you find yourself in trouble for small bits of code you placed here and there. Why not simply you use setLocationRelativeTo(null); or setLocationByPlatform(true), that will do.

Comment: No `pack()`? Before `setVisible()` of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Myself, I'd use a JOptionPane not a JFrame to create this dialog:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class UserIdPasswordPanel extends JPanel {
   JTextField selectionField = new JTextField(10);
   JTextField userIDField = new JTextField(10);
   JTextField passwordField = new JTextField(10);

   public UserIdPasswordPanel(JFrame frame) {
      add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Login") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            LoginPane loginPane = new LoginPane(UserIdPasswordPanel.this,
                  "My Login Panel");
            int result = loginPane.show();
            System.out.println("" + result);
            if (result >= 0) {
               String selectionText = LoginPane.options[result].toString();
               if (selectionText.equals(LoginPane.LOGIN)) {
                  System.out.println("do some login action here");
               } else if (selectionText.equals(LoginPane.RESET)) {
                  System.out.println("do some reset action here");
               }

               // just to show that this works:
               selectionField.setText(selectionText);
               userIDField.setText(loginPane.getUserId());

               // !! never do this !!!!!
               passwordField.setText(new String(loginPane.getPassword()));
            }
         }
      }));
      selectionField.setEditable(false);
      userIDField.setEditable(false);
      passwordField.setEditable(false);
      add(new JLabel("Selection: "));
      add(selectionField);
      add(new JLabel("ID: "));
      add(userIDField);
      add(new JLabel("Password: "));
      add(passwordField);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("UserIdPasswordPanel");

      UserIdPasswordPanel mainPanel = new UserIdPasswordPanel(frame);

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class LoginPane {
   public static final String LOGIN = "Login";
   public static final String RESET = "Reset";
   public static final Object[] options = { LOGIN, RESET };
   private JTextField userIdField = new JTextField(10);
   private JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);
   private Component parent;
   private String title;
   private JPanel message = new JPanel();

   public LoginPane(Component parent, String title) {
      this.parent = parent;
      this.title = title;

      message.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

      GridBagConstraints gbc = getGbc(0, 0);
      message.add(new JLabel("User ID:"), gbc);
      gbc = getGbc(1, 0);
      message.add(userIdField, gbc);
      gbc = getGbc(0, 1);
      message.add(new JLabel("Password:"), gbc);
      gbc = getGbc(1, 1);
      message.add(passwordField, gbc);
   }

   private GridBagConstraints getGbc(int x, int y) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
      gbc.anchor = (x == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.WEST : GridBagConstraints.EAST;
      return gbc;
   }

   public String getUserId() {
      return userIdField.getText();
   }

   public char[] getPassword() {
      return passwordField.getPassword();
   }

   public int show() {
      Object initialValue = "Login";
      return JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(parent, message, title,
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
            options, initialValue);
   }
}
```